# Multiplicative Euclidean Function for an Euclidean Domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory

> Does there exist an Euclidean domain with no *multiplicative* Euclidean function?

An Euclidean domain, denoted $R$, is an integral domain

with an Euclidean function $d : R\setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb{N}$ such that

$1)\quad d(a) \leq d(ab)$, and

$2)\quad a = bq + r$ with either $r = 0$ or $d(r) < d(b)$.

I am interested in multiplicative Euclidean functions. That is, $d(ab) = d(a)d(b)$.

For example, one can choose

$\mathbb{Z}$ with $d(n) = |n|, \quad \mathbb{Z}[i]$ with $d(\alpha) = N(\alpha), \quad F[X]$ with $d(f) = 2^{\deg(f)}$ for a field $F$,

or, kind of a stupid example, any field $F$ with $d(a) = 1$.

I am new here. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are [various definitions](http://journals.tubitak.gov.tr/math/issues/mat-95-19-3/pp-291-299.pdf) in use for Euclidean domains.  Generally one requires only condition (2) on the Euclidean function, and Euclidean functions satisfying the additional condition (1) are called *submultiplicative*. But, in fact, no generality is lost by assuming (1) since it can be show that every Euclidean domain admits a submultiplicative Euclidean function, viz. the minimal function

$$ d_{\min}(a) = \min\, \{d(a)\ :\ d\ \text{ is a Euclidean function on}\ R\}$$

However, it is currently *unknown* if one loses generality by replacing "submultiplicative" by "multiplicative", i.e. it is not known if every Euclidean domain admits a multiplicative Euclidean function (e.g. see the remark following Proposition 2.2 in Franz Lemmermeyer's excellent survey [The Euclidean algorithm in algebraic number fields](http://www.rzuser.uni-heidelberg.de/~hb3/publ/survey.pdf)).

Answer (score 19):

This question has now been answered.  There is a Euclidean domain but no Euclidean function for that ring into $\mathbb{N}$ is multiplicative.  See [my paper here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.02631).