# A question of Euclidean domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, euclidean-domain

We know the definition of ED only assume that the existence of an Euclidean function in which Euclidean algorithm works.

My question is: Could we request the Euclidean function is multiplicative in addition?

Comment: You mean $f(xy) = f(x)+f(y)$?

Comment: @DustanLevenstein I mean $f(xy)=f(x)f(y)$.

Comment: To my surprise, the answer to this question is unknown, or at least it was as of 2013. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/274606/multiplicative-euclidean-function-for-an-euclidean-domain for more

Comment: @AlexWertheim oh... Thanks.